# How to test passing vector arguments to a function

Tags: c++

I tried making a program that allowed me to add vocab cards for school. I would like to be able to test it all without having to make a vector, for example, here is my function

```
void AddCard(string Vocab_Word, vector<string> definitions, int definition_count)
```

The thing is that I don't know how I could appropriately pass in arguments for large testing purposes with vectors. I want to pass an argument like this:

```
AddCard("Earthquakes", {"They shake", "Everyone hates it"}, 2);
```

but I get errors from doing that. Does anyone have any input on how I may be able to fix this issue? Thanks for your help!!

I used a vector because I never am sure how many definitions will be stored (that's why I have the definition counter argument)

Comment: "I get errors" - and what are they?

Comment: I don't get any errors using your example but it may be worth passing the vector by reference rather than by value.

Comment: im sorry to waste your time. I figured it out. I accidentally added an extra argument on my function call. Thanks everyone for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

```
AddCard("Earthquakes", {"They shake", "Everyone hates it"}, 2);
```

This call *should* work - and indeed did for **Galik** - so long as your compiler is set up to use the C++11 standard or later. The `{braced, list}` is deduced to an `std::initializer_list`, which *can* be used to construct a `vector` (and many other STL containers). This avoids you having to create a named temporary `vector` (and repeated `push_`/`emplace_back()`s) and instead constructs your argument directly.

Maybe you just forgot to include the right option when compiling? If you're using GCC a.k.a. `g++`, then add `-std=c++11` - or even better, `-std=c++14` - to your command-line options. If your compiler is something else, then consult its documentation to see how to use the latest and greatest Standard.

Also, as mentioned by others, the 3rd parameter giving the `vector` length is totally unnecessary as `vector`s maintain and expose their own size. This is deliberately one of their main features/benefits. Use `yourVector.size()`, or in cases where you simply need to iterate over all values without caring how many, a range `for`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear... I assume you are asking how to pass large vectors of data to a function? Here's an example:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void AddCard(std::string vocab_word, std::vector<std::string> definitions, int definition_count) {
// do something
}

int main() {
   std::string test_string = "Hello earthquake";
   std::vector<std::string> test_vector {"They shake", "Everyone hates it"};

   AddCard(test_string, test_vector, 1); 

   // passing a vector explicitly
   AddCard(test_string, {"Still shaking", "Oh no"}, 2); 

   // add an element to the end of the vector
   test_vector.push_back("They shake again") 

   // etc ...

   return 1;
}
```

You don't really need the third argument as someone already pointed out, you can just call `definitions.size()` as your vector gets larger, which returns the size of your vector.

Also it's bad practice to have a `using namespace std` line at your file, you should declare the namespace manually like above.

Comment: yes, your assumption is correct. I can use the size, that is correct. Is there any way I could do this without making a temporary vector? If not, I could work with that. Ideally, I want to make this as easy as possible for someone to test this program as much as they desire, and being able to put it all in the function call will probably make it easier for them to do.

Comment: "Is there any way I could do this without making a temporary vector?" With no temporary except your function argument, yes, it's basic C++11; see my answer.

Comment: Yes of course you can just pass the vector explicitly. See the updated code above.

Comment: @ItoA The question is that the OP already tried that but, for some reason, it gives errors, which they still haven't quoted...

Comment: @underscore_d ah I see, well it seems to work for me, not sure what the issue is then

Comment: @ItoA I think it's just forgetting to pass a switch to the compiler to enable C++11 features. It seems to take a bewilderingly long time for mainstream compilers to make the latest C++ Standard version their default, or the OP might be using an outdated compiler anyway.

Comment: @underscore_d ahh that's probably the issue then, he can just compile with the -std=gnu++0x flag then, g++ should do this by default, makes the learning curve a little bit more steeper when you have little issues like this

Comment: @ItoA Unless one has a really convincing justification, I'd strongly advise maintaining portable, Standard-compliant code by not using GNU extensions. `-std=c++11` would be the recommended mode. GCC 6 is _slightly?_ better in that it makes `-std=gnu++14` default... which I immediately override with `-std=c++14` for the reasons already given. But yes, I wonder whether we have popular compilers to blame for a large proportion of the historically slow uptake of new C/++ standards.

Comment: @underscore_d thank you for this valuable piece of information.

Answer (score 0):

First you have an inconsistency in the type of `Vocab_Word`. From the way you are using it it appears to be a string, if so make it a string. If it is really supposed to be an int, figure out what constant you need to be passing to it to mean "Earthquakes". I will assume it is really supposed to be a string and that you have fixed `AddCard` function accordingly.

Then I would do it like this:

```
vector<string> definitions;
definitions.push_back("They shake");
definitions.push_back("Everyone hates it");
AddCard("Earthquakes", definitions, definitions.size());
```

Note that perhaps the third argument in `AddCard` is unnecessary because the vector knows how big it is (reported by `size()`). You only need it if you want to tell your function to use the first `n` elements of a given vector.

Comment: The `push_back()` boilerplate is only necessary if the OP can't use C++11 or later. If they can, the `initializer_list` constructor that takes the syntax given in the OP's post is superior, and in fact obviates any need to declare a named temporary vector to pass. I think the OP just forgot to pass a switch to enable C++11 or later mode.

Answer (score -2):

If i were you, i would use an array of strings instead of vector. You can do

```
std::string defn[2];
defn[0]+="They shake";
defn[1]+="Everyone hates it"
```

Your function prototype will change a little as follows

```
void AddCard(std::string Vocab_Word,std::string definitions[], int definition_count)
```

Comment: Most people would recommend a vector over an array.

Comment: Why? A variable length array is... a vector. or an `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: The size of the definitions is unknown. I want the user to put in as many definitions as they want to and it will work fine and I wont have too large of a array in the function either.